# scrollbar movement for canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I need help with a canvas scrollbar. I made a canvas inside the tkinter window; placed a canvas and a picture in this window. There may be several pictures. Additionally, the code for the vertical scrollbar is inserted. I need a sample code for a variant in which when moving the scrollbar slider : inside the canvas, pictures moved vertically. Below is an example of my code. Thank you in advance.

```
  import tkinter as tk
  from tkinter import ttk
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib as plt
  from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
  from matplotlib.figure import Figure
  import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
  import matplotlib
  matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
  
  class Main_LEAS(tk.Tk):
     def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()
         self.frame=tk.Frame()
         self.init_main()
         self._second_window=None
         self.buildbutton()
     def buildbutton(self):
         self.buttonOne=tk.Button(self.frame, text="Analys", width=25)
         self.buttonOne.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: (self.clear(),self.runOne()))
         self.buttonOne.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)
     def clear(self):
         list=root.winfo_children()
         for l in list:
             l.destroy()
     def init_main(self):
         toolbar=tk.Frame(bd=2)
         toolbar.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
         self.frame.pack()
     def plot(self):
         self.frame=root
         self.frame.geometry('850x650+50+50')
         self.canvas=tk.Canvas(self.frame, highlightthickness=0, bg="grey",
                          width=500, height=600)
         self.canvas.place(x=250,y=100)
         self.frame_plot=tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
         self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame_plot, anchor="nw")
         fig=Figure(figsize=(5, 5),
                  dpi=100)
         y = [i**2 for i in range(101)]
         plot1=fig.add_subplot(111)
         plot1.plot(y)
         self.canvas=FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,self.frame)
         self.canvas.draw()
         self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=2, column=3, sticky="nsew", padx=60, pady=50)
         self.vsb=tk.Scrollbar(self.frame, orient="vertical")
         self.vsb.place(x=800, y=50, height=200)
         self.vsb["command"]=self.canvas.get_tk_widget().yview
         self.canvas.get_tk_widget()["yscrollcommand"]=self.vsb.set
         self.canvas.get_tk_widget().yview
     def runOne(self):
         self.frame=root
         self.frame.geometry('850x650+50+50')
         self.buildbutton()
         self.buttonOne=tk.Button(self.frame, text="Analys", width=25)
         self.buttonOne.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: (self.clear(),self.runOne()))
         self.plot_button=tk.Button(master=self.frame, 
                  command=self.plot,height=2,width=10,text="Plot")
         self.plot_button.place(x=100,y=50)
         return self


 if __name__ == "__main__":
     root=Main_LEAS()
     root.title("LEAS500")
     root.geometry('460x150+500+100')
     root.resizable(False,False)
     root.config(bg="DodgerBlue4")
     root.mainloop()
```

The general view is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0yMw.jpg)

Comment: There are many issues in your code: 1) in `plot()` you define `self.canvas` twice, first as a tkinter canvas and then as a matplotlib figure canvas, 2) the `self.frame_plot` you put in the canvas does not contain anything, 3) you override the `self.frame` defined in `__init__()` in `plot()`, 4) you do not define the `scrollregion` of the canvas so there is nothing to scroll (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter/3092341#3092341), and probably other things I missed since I did not read through everything

Comment: minimal example for `Canvas` with `Scrollbar` on my GitHub: [python-examples / tkinter / canvas-scrollbar / main.py](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/__canvas__/canvas-scrollbar/main.py). It use `scrollbar.configure(command=canvas.yview)` and `canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))`

Comment: @furas ,@j_4321 : Good evening. After reading your answers, I did not understand how to fix everything. Your answers are logically correct - I also thought so, but not having figured out how to solve the problem, I wrote here. Could you, using my code as an example, show how to correctly bind plot to the canvas and, at the same time, so that the scrollbar works

Comment: I tried to modify your code but it still doesn't work for me. Maybe I will use my class `ScrolledFrame` to modify all your code. See source code [python-examples / tkinter / scrolled-frame-canvas / scrolledframe.py](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/scrolled-frame-canvas/scrolledframe.py). There are other examples for Python, Tkinter and Matplotlib.

Comment: I think I found problem - you need `.bind('<Configure>', function)` to update external canvas size after adding inner canvas with plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding plot to frame canvas doesn't know that frame has new size and that canvas should have new `scroll region`.

It needs to bind event `<Configure>` to function which will update `scroll region` when you add plot. If you would set `scroll region` directly in `plot()` then it would do this before tkinter adds items to canvas.

BTW: you use the same variable `self.canvas` for external canvas and for matplotlib canvas - so I use variable `self.outer_canvas` for external canvas

```py
def plot(self):

    # ...
 
    self.frame_plot.bind('<Configure>', self.resize)
    
def resize(self, event=None): 
    # resize outer_canvas when frame_plot changes size - ie. when it draws plot at start

    #self.outer_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.outer_canvas.bbox('all'))
    self.outer_canvas['scrollregion'] = self.outer_canvas.bbox('all')
```

---

Full working code with some other changes.

I had to set smaller outer canvas (500x300 instead of 500x600) because plot had the same size (500x600) and there was nothing to scroll.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')


class Main_LEAS(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.frame = tk.Frame()
        self.init_main()
        self._second_window = None
        self.build_button()
         
    def build_button(self):  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions and variables
        self.button_one = tk.Button(self.frame, text='Analys', width=25)
        self.button_one.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: (self.clear(),self.run_one()))
        self.button_one.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)
         
    def clear(self):
        # don't use variable `list` because there is built-in function `list()` 
        for child in root.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()
             
    def init_main(self):
        toolbar = tk.Frame(bd=2)
        toolbar.pack(side='top', fill='x')
        self.frame.pack()
         
    def plot(self):
        self.frame = root
        self.frame.geometry('850x650+50+50')
        
        self.outer_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.frame, highlightthickness=0, bg='grey', width=500, height=300)
        self.outer_canvas.place(x=250, y=100)

        self.frame_plot = tk.Frame(self.outer_canvas, background='#ffffff')
        self.outer_canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame_plot, anchor='nw')

        fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        y = [i**2 for i in range(101)]
        plot1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
        plot1.plot(y)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self.frame_plot)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=2, column=3, sticky='nsew', padx=60, pady=50)
        
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.frame, orient='vertical')
        self.vsb.place(x=800, y=50, height=200)
        self.vsb['command'] = self.outer_canvas.yview
        
        self.outer_canvas['yscrollcommand'] = self.vsb.set
        self.outer_canvas['scrollregion'] = self.outer_canvas.bbox('all')

        self.canvas.draw()
         
        # execute function when frame changes size - ie. when it draws plot at start
        self.frame_plot.bind('<Configure>', self.resize)
        
    def resize(self, event=None): 
        # resize outer_canvas when frame changes size - ie. when it draws plot at start
        #self.outer_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.outer_canvas.bbox('all'))
        self.outer_canvas['scrollregion'] = self.outer_canvas.bbox('all')
            
    def run_one(self):
        self.frame = root
        self.frame.geometry('850x650+50+50')
        
        self.build_button()
        
        self.plot_button = tk.Button(master=self.frame, command=self.plot, height=2, width=10, text='Plot')
        self.plot_button.place(x=100, y=50)


if __name__ == '__main__':
     root = Main_LEAS()
     root.title('LEAS500')
     root.geometry('460x150+500+100')
     root.resizable(False, False)
     root.config(bg='DodgerBlue4')
     root.mainloop()
```

[image]

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

You may use tool like [WinMerge](https://winmerge.org/) or [Meld](https://meldmerge.org/) to compare my code with your code

Comment: your code example is not working . there is a scrollbar, but there is no slider and, accordingly, there is no movement

Comment: code works for me - like on animation - but I tested it on Linux Mint, Python 3.10,

Comment: i have windows 7 and python 3.8

Comment: can anyone show me a working code example for windows 7? Could it be because of the operating system?

Comment: @MIKKIMOUSE This solution works in my Windows 7 and Python 3.8.18.

Comment: @furas : Good afternoon. My code has worked. There was an error in the code above (in one line). The line self.outer_canvas['scrollregion']=self.outer_canvas.bbox('all') should be replaced with
         self.outer_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.scrollregion)
and then the slider in the scrollbar moves the picture itself inside the canvas.  Thank you in general.